# Set Background Image for Apple Watch Notification

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I am trying to change the background from a plain color on a custom static notification to a picture, similar to American Airlines, allowing the text to be written on top of a picture.  I add in my image in Storyboard, but the text just stays above it.

Comment: are u adding programmatically? could u please share your code?

Comment: Not adding programmatically, just in storyboard...  Which is what I said in the original post.